# No export statement in App.vue, but App module is imported in main.ts. How is this possible?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

In the example router project generated by Vue CLI, I don't see export statement in App.vue. But App module is found imported in main.ts. How the import of a module is made possible without an export statement?

But I see the export statement in App.vue of a non-router example project.

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");
```

App.vue of router example project

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>

<style>
...
</style>
```

App.vue of a non-router example project

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

@Options({
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

Comment: This could be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038615/in-vue-js-why-do-we-have-to-export-components-after-importing-them
TL;DR: You don't need to export .vue files in order to be able to import them into other components or files.

Comment: Thank you for responding. But my doubt is still not cleared If the export is not needed, then why is it there in the App.vue of a non-router example project?